# Removing line breaks from CSV exported from Google Sheets

Tags: sed, google-sheets, newline

I have some data in the format:

```
-e, 's/,Chalk/,Cheese/g'

-e, 's/,Black/,White/g'

-e, 's/,Leave/,Remain/g'
```

in a file data.csv.

Using Gitbash, I use the file command to discover that this is ASCII text with CRLF terminators. If I also use the command cat -v , I see in Gitbash that each line ends ^M .

I want to remove those terminators, to leave a single line.

I've tried the following:

```
sed -e 's/'\r\n'//g' < data.csv > output.csv
```

taking care to put the \r\n in single quotes in order that the backslash is treated literally, but it does not work. No error, just no effect.

I'm using Gitbash for Windows.

Comment: Why not just `CLEAN` the data before exporting to csv?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your point, but whatever I do in Google Sheets, it will still come out as CSV with line terminators, which are the issue.

Comment: You're not putting the `\r\n` inside single quotes, you're taking them OUT of the single quotes. It sounds like you just need to run `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes within quotes cancel each other out, so you actually undo the quotes around the sed command for the newline characters. You could escape the quotes like `'s|'\''\r\n'\''||g'`, but that would just include them in the string, which would not match anything in your case.

But that is not the only problem; `sed` by default only processes strings between newlines.

If you have the GNU version of `sed`, RAM to spare if the file is huge, and are sure the file does not contain data with null characters, try adding [the `-z` argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options), like:

```
sed -z -e 's|\r\n||g' < data.csv > output.csv
```

Though I guess you probably also want to replace it with a comma:

```
sed -z -e 's|\r\n|,|g' < data.csv > output.csv
```

For non-GNU versions of `sed`, you may have an easier time using `tr` instead, like:

```
tr '\r\n' ',' data.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: Many thanks @svenper : this seems to work, although some text editors still seem to think that there are line breaks while others don't. But, according to the cat and file commands, the breaks have gone.

Comment: You should mention that `-z` will read the whole input file into memory which may be undesirable if the file is huge. Also, I THINK `-z` is GNU-only so that should be stated too if it's true.